# How to Hide or cancel Push notification in iOS ( Uiusernotification or RemoteNotification) which comes from apns in background mode and lock screen?

Tags: ios, push-notification

In my app RemoteNotification is repeated so i want to handle them if they are repeated i want to hide them if not wants to show.

How to Hide or cancel Push notification in iOS ( Uiusernotification or RemoteNotification) which comes from apns in background mode and lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

put above code wherever you want Hide or cancel APN.